# MVVM Update Property A when Property B changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ComboBox and DataGrid setup like so:

```
<ComboBox Name="PayrollDatasesListBox"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding PayrollDatabasesList}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPayrollDatabase}" />

    <DataGrid Name="RateTable"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RateTableDataView}"
              Margin="20"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              Width="775"> ...
    </DataGrid>
```

In the ViewModel I have the following properties:

```
    public ObservableCollection<String> PayrollDatabasesList
    {
        get
        {
            DelphiaConfigModel _config = (App.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator).SystemSetupViewModel.DelphiaConfigInfo;
            return new ObservableCollection<String>(_config.DatabaseInfo.PayrollDatabaseNames.Split(',')
                .Select(c => c.ToString().Trim())
                .ToList());
        }
    }

    public String SelectedPayrollDatabase { 
        get
        {
            return _SelectedPayrollDatabase;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedPayrollDatabase != value)
            {
                _SelectedPayrollDatabase = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.SelectedPayrollDatabase);
            }
        }
    }
    public String _SelectedPayrollDatabase;

    public DataView RateTableDataView
    {
        get
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("TempDataSet");

            // Get reference to DelphiaConfigInfo
            DelphiaConfigModel _config = 
                (App.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator).SystemSetupViewModel.DelphiaConfigInfo;

            using (SQLClass _sql = new SQLClass(_config.DatabaseInfo))
            {
                using (SqlConnection _conn = _sql.Connection)
                {
                    // use the chosen Payroll Database from ComboBox
                    //TODO: set InitialCatalog to selected database
                    SqlConnectionStringBuilder _newConn =
                        new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(_conn.ConnectionString) { InitialCatalog = SelectedPayrollDatabase };
                    _conn.ConnectionString = _newConn.ConnectionString;

                    //_conn.ChangeDatabase("SageHRMS_BKC");

                    SqlCommand _cmd = _conn.CreateCommand();
                    _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    _cmd.CommandText = "aem.S_RateTable_SP";

                    SqlDataAdapter _adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);

                    _adapter.Fill(ds);
                }
            }

            return ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
    }
```

How can I update RateTableDataView when SelectedPayrollDatabase changes?

Comment: Honestly, you shouldn't put stuff like SQL Queries into your bindable Properties, it will lock the UI. Better to implement an async command, which will update the property with the `DataView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something but you can just update from the setter for your selected payroll database.

Or just call the PropertyChanged event from INotifyPropertyChanged passing your property name.

Something like...

```
NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.RateTableDataView);
```

Comment: Not sure I follow you, can you give an example?  What would I call within the SelectedPayrollDatabase setter to get the RateTableDataView getter to fire?

Comment: It's why I said I might be missing something, are you wanting the binding to update in your UI?

Comment: I've edited the answer to show the notification you can set in your 'selected' property to cause the UI to Get.